# Passing two options as arguments in OpenCL with Fortran (CLFORTRAN)

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, opencl, gpgpu, fortran90

When my host program is in C language I can pass two options as an argument of an OpenCL function. For example, I can pass two
flags to the `clCreateBuffer` function like this:

```
clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                            sizeof(main_data), main_data, &err)
```

However, when I try to do the same in a host program written in Fortran:

```
main_data=clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, &
                               sizeof(main_data), C_NULL_PTR, err)
```

I get an error:

```
 &     |CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, size_in_bytes,C_NULL_PTR,ierr)        
       1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
```

I have successfully compiled some other programs with CLFORTRAN, but whenever I try to pass two flags like `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` I get the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C bitwise or `|` cannot be used in Fortran. You have to use `+`. The `ior()` function would probably also work, but I would use `+`*. It works because the valued of the constants are normally designed in such a way that they have only one `1` bit and every time at a different position.

*If you do use `+` you may not add the same flag twice, it flags would be computed incorrectly.

Comment: Why the downvote? Thu summation is really used in many official bindings like FFTW and others.

Comment: No problem, downvotes happen. I just want to make clear that the solution I offered is commonly done, it is not something dubious I invented.